# Loading big data sets to ArrayList in Java (max capacity of ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist, biginteger, large-data, bigdata

I am trying to load a data sets of more than 2^32 elements, and put those elements in an ArrayList `anArrayList`. This data is in chronological order, so I use ArrayList to store the data to keep the order. At the same time, I want to get quick access to the elements from an String `elementID`. Now I am using HashMap to map a `elementID` to the element Object in `anArrayList`. 
I used an integer `currentAddingAt` to keep tracking the index on anArrayList to adding the element. Here is the related code:

```
ArrayList<ElementX> anArrayList;
int currentAddingAt;
HashMap<String, ElementX> elementToObjHashMap;

... ...

public void addAnElement(ElementX e){
    anArrayList.add(currentAddingAt, e);
    elementToObjHashMap.put(e.getElementID, ArrayList.get(currentAddingAt));  
}
```

A problem came when I changed the type of `currentAddingAt` from `int` to `long`. Because ArrayList's `get(int index)` method only takes `int` as an argument, according to Oracle's documentation(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). This also makes me wondering:

Can ArrayList's capacity larger than the largest int number in Java(2^32)?

What are the options other than using ArrayList and HashMap in this case (to keep the order of a large data set and still have ability to get quick mapping from a key to the object)? Do I need some library (or even some framework) other then plain Java?

Comment: You can switch to a LinkedList implementation to overcome Integer.MAX_VALUE size problem of ArrayList, but probably there is a better way instead of load entire data in memory.

Comment: this link might give you some idea - [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630998/how-to-make-a-big-array-in-java)

Comment: Any suggestions on what other strategy that I can use? The way this data is used is: Information in a large portion of those elements are read and write to calculate information dynamically in real time. Will some kind of database provide the speed of fast fetch and modification of data in the elements? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can ArrayList's capacity larger than the largest int number in Java(2^32)?

No. Because it's array-backed, it can't be larger than 2^31-1. This applies to all `Collections` if you want the `size()` and `toArray()` methods to work.

You'll need to store lists of lists, but I bet there's a library that can do it. I haven't used that part of it, but [Fastutil has big data structures](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/#big) in addition to its primitive data structures.