# initializing Byte array with size of "Long" data type?

Tags: java, byte, arrays, long-integer

So i have this method to read the data in a file into a byte array with starting point "offset" and length o "len" :

```
public static byte[] readFileDataToByteArray( File inFile, long offset, int len ) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[ len ];

    try {
        RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile( inFile, "r" );
        in.seek( off );
        in.read( buffer );          
        in.close();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        System.err.println("Error readSentence: Error reading " + inFile ); 
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

now this is working just fine as long as the `len` variable does not exceed the maximum allowed int value. but when I have to use "long" as data type of variable `len` to be able to pass larger numbers (i.e to create lager arrays), I get the following error :

```
../util/Common.java:564: error: possible loss of precision
    byte[] buffer = new byte[ len ];
                              ^
required: int
found:    long
1 error
```

So basically all I need to do is to create a byte array with a size of a "long" data type. any hints ?

Comment: Uhm; you _are_ aware that any `long` that doesn't fit an `int` means that its value is 2^31 or more, aren't you? Why don't you just do `new byte[(int) len]`?

Comment: of course i am aware. in fact the number in my program exceeded 2^31-1 and then was converted to a negative number (at the other end of int range). the casting to int does not solve the problem because the number will be again negative after casting or at best it would be MAX_INT which is not what i want. i want the original long number to be the length of the byte array

Comment: OK, wait; are you serious? do you _really_ intend to create such a large array? It looks to me that there should be another solution than that. What if you stated what you wanted to do instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a big array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630998/how-to-make-a-big-array-in-java)

Comment: well, its just that im reading a large file (about 4Gb) and i want to create a ByteArrayInputStream object with that for which as an argument i will need a byte array.hence calling the method above. now what is your alternative suggestion ?

Comment: You'd probably be better off mmap'ing your file and processing it in chunks, if possible, or if you need to read it as a stream, reading some and processing in chunks where it makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, you stumble upon limitations which cannot be overriden in Java... You need to process in chunks. Also, have a look at `FileChannel`; or write/find JNI code over the OS' `mmap()` (if you run a Unix system).

Comment: thanks guys. seems like i have to find another way ...

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried. That the biggest array size can't exceed the heap size. So it's better to process the file in several time if it could be.

```
public class RandomAccessFileTest {
    static public class LargeArray {
        public long offset;
        public long len;
        public int arraySize; // can't exceed JVM heap size
        byte[] byte_arr;

        public LargeArray(long offset, long len, int arraySize) {
            this.offset = offset;
            this.len    = len;
            this.arraySize = arraySize;
        }
    }

    public static LargeArray readFileDataToByteArray(File inFile, LargeArray  array) {
        long count = array.len/array.arraySize;
        if (array.len > 0 ) {
            try{
                int arr_len = (count == 0) ? (int)array.len:array.arraySize;
                array.byte_arr = new byte[arr_len];
                RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile( inFile, "r" );
                in.seek( array.offset );
                in.read( array.byte_arr );          
                in.close();

                array.offset += arr_len;
                array.len    -= arr_len;
                return array;
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                System.err.println("Error readSentence: Error reading " + inFile ); 
                System.exit(1);
            }       
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LargeArray array = new LargeArray(5,1000000, 10000);
        File file = new File("test.txt");

        while((array = readFileDataToByteArray(file, array)) != null) {
            System.out.println(new String(array.byte_arr));
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably check out this link [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485128/how-do-i-convert-long-to-byte-and-back-in-java)

A word of cauuion, always check out for the range of primitives before tycasting them.
Here in you want a byte array size to take the long value which seems to me a invalid scenario since long can have precision in it's scope. Flooring/ceiling of the precision value would certainly result in loss of precision.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. They are asking how to do `new byte[someLong]`.